# Using html.ParseFragment in a generic way

Tags: go

Using the experimental `code.google.com/p/go.net/html` package, we can use `ParseFragment` to parse some sub-section of an HTML document.

Like this:

```
var s = `
    <option id="foo">first</option>
    <option Class="tester">second</option>
    <option>third</option>
`
doc, err := html.ParseFragment(strings.NewReader(s), &html.Node{
    Type: html.ElementNode,
    Data: "body",
    DataAtom: atom.Body,
})
```

This works fine for most elements. But it doesn't seem to work when certain elements are at the root position of the HTML, like `tbody`, `tr`, and `td` (and perhaps others, not sure). It simply ignores the tags and only gives the text content.

This can be remedied by providing the semantically correct parent instead of `atom.Body`, but that requires that we know in advance what the HTML will be.

I'd hoped there was a generic root like `atom.DocumentFragment`, but I don't see that. So is there some way to use this in such a manner that it'll work with any arbitrary HTML fragment?

Comment: What are you doing with the HTML fragment after you parse it?

Comment: From some limited testing I would wait until this is more finalized. I am getting some strange results by parsing different fragments. However for your specific case, I was able to get it to parse a tbody fragment by passing nil as the node context.

Comment: @andybalholm: The parsed result has some specific processing performed on it and the final result is cached away for later use.

Comment: @DanielWilliams: When I parse a fragment like `<tbody><tr><td>some text</td></tr></tbody>` with a `nil` context, it returns a document structure with `html` at the root, and the `some text` text as the content of the `body`. Your result was different?

Comment: @DanielWilliams Don't wait for the library to be finalized. It is feature-complete and passes all tests. The only thing keeping it out of the standard library is that we aren't sure if the API is exactly what we'll want in the long term. Believe it or not, the bizarre behavior you're seeing is what the spec requires.

Comment: @andybalholm: I wondered if it may be following the spec in that behavior. Considering that there will be fragments the structure of which is unknown at the time of parsing, it would seem useful to have a generic node that can be the parent of any element. Following the spec is great, but it would seem odd to follow it so strictly if there's going to be a `ParseFragment` feature.

Comment: @cookiemonster My point is that HTML is inherently context-sensitive. So the parse tree corresponding to a given string varies depending on where it is in the document. So you have to know something about what you are doing with an HTML fragment before you can parse it correctly. (Note that ParseFragment should give the same parse tree as you would get by assigning to the context element's innerHTML property in a browser.)

Comment: @andybalholm: I understand the dilemma. My point is that it doesn't seem useful to have a `ParseFragment` feature that doesn't work on some fragments. Following the spec is great, but at the end of the day, this isn't assigning  to an element's `.innerHTML`. This is needing to parse a fragment of HTML on a server.

Comment: @cookiemonster It would be easier to write a simpler HTML parser, without the error-recovery and context sensitivity, than to provide a way to turn them off on an HTML5 parser.

Comment: @andybalholm: So it seems that there is no solution to my problem when using this package *(other than perhaps manually analyzing the root nodes)*. If you'd kindly post an answer that states that along with the explanation you offered in your comments, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ParseFragment` is always context-sensitive because it follows the HTML5 fragment-parsing algorithm. That algorithm is designed for implementing the DOM innerHTML property, and the correct tree to generate from a given innerHTML string depends on the surrounding context (especially whether the context is in a table or not).

So the `html` package has no way to parse an HTML fragment independently of its context.

If you need more information about how the parsing depends on the context, see http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/parsing.html#reset-the-insertion-mode-appropriately