# Parsing Tags in HTML using go

Tags: html, go

I am trying to test if the string has  tag. I a new to using go. My go code is below. I first parse the string by invoking html.Parse then search for  tag. This logic does not seems to be working. Am I making some mistake here ?

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "golang.org/x/net/html"
  "log"
  "strings"
)


func main() {


 var  script = "<script>alert(\"Hello World\");</script>"
 n,err := html.Parse(strings.NewReader(script))
 if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        fmt.Printf("%s",err)
    }

var f func(*html.Node)
f = func(n *html.Node) {
     if n.Type == html.ElementNode && n.Data == "script" {
         fmt.Printf("Found Script Tag")
       }
     }

 f(n)

}
```

Comment: `Parse` doesn't work this way. It expects a whole HTML *document*. When parsing your `<script>`, it will create full HTML tree nonetheless, starting with a `DocumentNode` (`<html>`) and a `<head>` and a `<body>` and so on.

Comment: There is `ParseFragment` but it doesn't work in all cases the way you think either.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21421704/using-html-parsefragment-in-a-generic-way

Comment: I appreciate the explanation. Thank you